# Correlation Coefficient for each independent variable in a multiple regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I ran the lm() function on R for a model with 5 independent variables? I want to find the correlation coefficient for each variables. The output from R does not give this. How do I find the correlation coefficient for several independent variables on R?

Comment: Try `cor` function. Also you might be interested in `vif`(car library))

Answer (score 0):

Just use the base R cor() function. If you have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(50, 0, 1), b = rnorm(50, 100, 15), c = rnorm(50, 80, 10))
```

You can just type:

```
cor(df)
```

To get all correlations in a matrix like this:

```
            a           b           c
a  1.00000000 -0.01272697  0.06223403
b -0.01272697  1.00000000 -0.23175382
c  0.06223403 -0.23175382  1.00000000
```

Altough I'm not quiet sure why you'd want to have the correlation in addition. All the information you need when you build a regression model you get by using broom functions.

```
reg <- lm(a ~ ., data = df)

library(broom) 
tidy(reg)
glance(reg)
```